# 404 en todas las páginas excepto homepage

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

he intentado casi todas las posibles soluciones que he visto online y ya no sé qué hacer.
https://amigoswgr.com
Estoy usando Wordpress con apache. Mis conocimientos de programación son nulos.
Todo empezó con un aviso de seguridad en Chrome y Firefox al entrar a la web. Mi hosting me ayudó a resolverlo, era un problema del SSL, tuve que reinstalarlo.
A partir de aquí ya podía entrar en el back end de la web, pero en el front end solo puedo entrar a la homepage, el resto de páginas me dan error 404.
Parece como si Apache estuviera ignorando el contenido de .htaccess.
Me he asegurado de que no es un problema de permalinks.
Mi http.conf se ve así:

```
<Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

He comprobado que el módulo mod_rewrite está activado en apache.
Lo próximo que he hecho es copiar el contenido de mi .htaccess en https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ , y así poder ver si las rewrite rules en el .htaccess son correctas.
Mi .htaccess tiene dos secciones distintas para mod_rewrite.c.
Esta:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteRule .* - [E=WPR_SSL:-https]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteRule .* - [E=WPR_ENC:_gzip]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !(wordpress_logged_in_.+|wp-postpass_|wptouch_switch_toggle|comment_author_|comment_author_email_) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/register/(.*)|/(.+/)?feed/?|/(?:.+/)?embed/|/checkout/(.*)|/cart/|/wc-api/v(.*)|/(index\.php/)?wp\-json(/.*|$))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(facebookexternalhit).* [NC]
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/index%{ENV:WPR_SSL}%{ENV:WPR_WEBP}.html%{ENV:WPR_ENC}" -f
RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/index%{ENV:WPR_SSL}%{ENV:WPR_WEBP}.html%{ENV:WPR_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
```

Y esta:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Al introduces todas las líneas de RewriteRule en dicha web, solo hay una línea que me da error:

RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

This rule was not met.

Estaría muy agradecido por cualquier ayuda que me pudieran dar, muchas gracias.